# Get rid of wasted/unused space in a JMenu

Tags: java, swing, menu

In my app, I've got a menu bar with a File menu.  In the submenus, each JMenuItem is wasting a lot of white space to the left of the text for a checkbox (I think), even though I'm not including any JCheckBoxMenuItems.

I'm seeing lots of other java/swing apps who's menus don't waste this space.  How do I do it in my app?

[image: Menu screen shot]

Comment: What makes you think it's trying to include a CheckBox?

What happens when you take out the images - is there still the space or is it gone?

Comment: I tested with the Metal and Windows UI look-and-feels on my system, and removing the icons from the menu items with icons caused all of the icons to move over to the left.  I believe that it is as-designed that most (all?) menu UIs line up the text labels, indenting as much as needed to make room for any icons or checkboxes that other menu items happen to have.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a default for your chosen [`UIManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) Look and Feel (L&F). You could try using [`put()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to change it. This handy [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) tool shows the effect of disparate `Menu.margin` values in various L&Fs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the menu UI is deliberately lining up the text of all of your menu items.  If none of your menu items had icons nor checkboxes, then none of them would have any space on the left for icons or checkboxes, either.

Personally, I wouldn't want to change this.  If you did figure out a way get rid of the "wasted space" next to your menu items that don't have icons, then your menu would have a jagged appearance.  If you changed this, then someone reading the menu would have to adjust to the fact that the left-hand baseline keeps changing as their eyes move down the menu list.

So, my advice would be either to get rid of *all* the icons or just to be happy that all of the menu items' text labels are vertically aligned with one another.